# Как посмотреть значения из std::vector в отладчике Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, отладка, clion

Есть простейший код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

На строке с `getchar();` стоит точка останова. Запускаю данный код в двух IDE: Visual Studio 2019 и CLion. При остановке на точке просматриваю значения локальных переменных, а именно, – вектора `v`. Вот что я вижу в CLion (это, с моей точки зрения, "отладчик здорового человека"):

[image: CLion]

А вот что показывает мне Visual Studio 2019:

[image: Visual Studio 2019]

Я понимаю, что вывод VS обоснован деталями реализации контейнера и, что, скорее всего, "под капотом" вектор именно так и выглядит. Но, тем не менее, CLion почему-то "соображает", что программист при отладке, скорее всего, хочет видеть "немного" не это. Более того, при работе с Visual Studio 2008, я не раз просматривал аналогичные векторы отладчиком и там, так же, как в CLion, элементы контейнера отображались в удобочитаемом виде (скриншот, к сожалению, приложить нет возможности).

Вопрос: что стало с отладчиком VS с момента версии 2008ого года и как сделать, чтобы он выводил мне полезную информацию, а не детали внутренней реализации контейнера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все прекрасно работает в студии. Даже лучше, чем в клионе. Просто не нужно в настройках трогать галочки разные. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и будет все выглядеть вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай, нужно пойти в Tools->Options.. , там Debugging -> General и снять галочку с "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows".

P.S. на месте разработчиков CLion  я бы специально эту галочку ставил. Для надежности:)

Comment: Хмм, не помню, чтобы я зачем-то менял эту настройку, но, видимо, всё-таки менял. В любом случае, большое спасибо, Ваш способ, конечно же, сработал.